# Python Django Forms to Add to Database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to use this form to add to a table in the database. I am currently getting the error "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.," but I was getting others errors with different tweaks to this code. How do I get this code to work and what is the best practice for writing a form like this?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Portfolio(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class CreatePortfolio(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from portfolio.models import Portfolio
from portfolio.forms import CreatePortfolio

def portfolio(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        portfolio_form = CreatePortfolio(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            csrf_token = django.middleware.csrf.get_token(request)
            port_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            port_description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            port_user = request.user
            new_portfolio = Portfolio(name=port_name, description=port_description, user=port_user)
            new_portfolio.save()
            return render_to_response('portfolio.html', {'csrf_token': csrf_token})
    else:
        portfolio_form = CreatePortfolio()
    return render_to_response('portfolio.html', {'portfolio_form': portfolio_form})
```

**portfolio.html**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="field">
        <label for="id_name">Name:</label>
            {{ portfolio_form.name}}
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="id_description">Description:</label>
        {{ portfolio_form.description }}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't adding the csrf token to your context in render_to_response.

Either use RequestContext to render your view (which automatically includes csrf in its context) like so:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def portfolio(request):
    # ... view code here
   return render_to_response("portfolio.html", {'portfolio_form': portfolio_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

or update the csrf manually like so:

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def portfolio(request):
    # ... view code here

    c = {'portfolio_form': portfolio_form}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response("portfolio.html", c)
```

See here for more references

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to explicitly send the csrf_token. Django takes care of it for you.

Every time a form is submitted, it verifies the token, and generates a new token for subsequent requests. Here, you are forcing it to use the same token, hence the error.

Your view should look something like this:

```
def portfolio(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        portfolio_form = CreatePortfolio(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            port_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            port_description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            port_user = request.user
            new_portfolio = Portfolio(name=port_name, description=port_description, user=port_user)
            new_portfolio.save()
            return render_to_response('portfolio.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        portfolio_form = CreatePortfolio()
    return render_to_response('portfolio.html', {'portfolio_form': portfolio_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```